# How one byte variables can stores two byte character constant?

Tags: c

In the following declaration statement

char c=’A’;

Variable c stores one byte of memory space while character constants ‘A’ stores two byte memory space. How one byte variables can stores two byte character constant?

Comment: Why do you think that `'A'` requires two bytes of memory?

Comment: what do you mean by "character constants ‘A’ stores two byte memory space"? The characters in the basic character set are guaranteed to fit in one byte (i. e. a `char`). If a character literal, of which the type is `int`, is wider, then its most significant bits/bytes are all zero, consequently truncating it to a `char` doesn't lead to loss of information.

Comment: In a declaration and initialization like that, the character literal may not actually require any space at all! If the variable is global, or if it's a local variable declared `static`, then the variable is initialized by the compiler at compilation time and the actual literal `'A'` isn't stored anywhere, so the literal is *zero* bytes.

Comment: Also, the size of a character literal (and `char` variable) doesn't *have* to be a byte, think old systems where characters were only 7 bits, or systems with 36-bit words (where characters most likely were 9 bits). But also, no matter the actual size of a character, `sizeof char` is specified to always return `1`.

Comment: @codegeek That won't really tell much, since `sizeof char` (or `sizeof(charVar)`) is defined by the C++ specification to always be `1`.

Comment: @codegeek You should use `%zu` to print values of type `size_t`.

Comment: If your compiler is happy with it, you can save your source in UTF-16 (where A takes 16 bits) and have it generate code for an 8-bit code-unit execution character encoding (where A takes 8 bits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C language, char type is used to store a 1 byte integer. When you assign 'A' to char c, you are not assigning the letter A itself into memory. Rather, you are assigning the number (integer) representing the A character. Each letter has a digit that represent it. . Remember that unlike humans, computers cannot understand letters. That's why we need a way to translate them into digits. To do this we use differnet coding styles like: ASCII, UTF-8, etc
If your machine use ASCII coding then the value assigned to char c would be 65 (0x41 hex). As you may notice, 0x41 is one byte and can be stored in your char variable.

You may consult this: http://www.asciitable.com/